# python bar graphs with many values in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying make a program where i want compared diferent proteins in 3 types of animals (CONT, BBN1, BBN2). 
This is part of my code:

```
plt.figure(1,figsize=(15,5))
ax = plt.subplot()
n_groups = len(protein)
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.3

rects1 = plt.bar(index - bar_width,bbn1,
                 bar_width,
                 color='b')

rects2 = plt.bar(index, cont, bar_width,
                 color='r',align='center')

rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, bbn2, bar_width,
                 color='g')

plt.title('Comparation of Protein\'s emPAI in BBN1, CONT, BBN2')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width*(2/3), protein,rotation='vertical', fontsize=5)
plt.yticks(fontsize=5)
plt.ylim([0, float(max(max(cont),max(bbn1),max(bbn2)))+5])
plt.xlim([0,n_groups]) 
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0],rects3[0]), ('BBN1','Cont','BBN2'))
plt.show()
```

When i run the code i obtain this figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV3XL.png)

How can i make a graph where i can see better the names in x axis?

Comment: What is the module you are using?

Comment: I'm using matplotlip